# Black MacBook WiFi drops when fan starts blowing

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro, airport

I have a 2007 Black MacBook running the latest version of Mac OS X Lion. It has a strange issue wherein the Airport shuts down if the fan starts blowing, and will not start up without a reboot.

Any ideas as to what would be causing this? All sorts of things can make the fan start, but the screensaver and iTunes visualizer are major culprits. It sometimes even does it when I have too many programs open for an extended period of time.

Does anyone have any ideas as to the cause of this? If so, what would be a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite an odd issue.  I would suggest re-installing OS X Lion and seeing if that rectifies the situation.  If that doesn't fix it, I'd take it to an Apple Authorised Service Provider (AASP) or an Apple Store - sounds like either the AirPort card or the Main Logic Board in that unit is faulty.  I wish I could look at that unit personally, I'd love to find the root of that issue.

Good Luck!

Comment: You were right! I finally got around to looking inside my BlackBook, and I found a burned spot on the corner of the Airport card. That would explain why it would start acting up when the system started getting hot.